# How to get reference of wxWidgets panel (listbox)?

Tags: c++, user-interface, reference, wxwidgets

I have a function in my wxWidgets application, which can be triggered by a certrain event (button push). Now I want to run in this function a method of a listbox I have in another panel, for displaying some entries etc. The listbox was instanciated in the onInit() method of the main applicationclass.

My question is, how do I get a reference to this listbox, so I can access it's printing methods?

Comment: A code sample would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you created the listbox you assigned it an ID.  Use that ID in a call to FindWindowById

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxwindow.html#wxwindowfindwindowbyid

```
// Construct listbox

wxListBox ( this, ID_LISTBOX );

...

// get pointer to listbox

wxListBox* pListBox = findwindowbyid( ID_LISTBOX )
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically, there is a class derived from your wxWidgets form, in which you do all your work. The parent class sets up the form, and the child class then has access to all its controls, because they are members of the parent class.

In short, each of your controls should be a member variable, to which you have access.

Using wxFormBuilder (or another graphical IDE) might be helpful, because they will generate the code for you, giving you a tried and true framework in which to make your changes.